# Como fazer o php esperar pelo valor vindo do click do Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema para avaliar um usuário (típico de estrelinhas), mas estou tendo problemas ao passar valores para o PHP.

Código Javascript:

```
   function mouseClick(id){
                var valorVoto = document.getElementById(id).value
                valorVoto = valorVoto.split("#")
                voto = valorVoto[4] 
                <?php $voto = "<script>document.write(voto)</script>"; ?>
            }
```

Código PHP:

```
    if(isset($voto)){
          echo 'Passou';
    }
```

Quando eu abro a página ele não espera pelo click do botão, simplesmente dá o echo.

Comment: Como o próprio nome do PHP (Hypertext Preprocessor) afirma, ela é uma linguagem pré-processada e por isso não não dá para fazer o que desejas. O PHP ele apenas processa o código e mostra o resultado, feito isso você só poderá utiliza-lo em uma nova requisição, por exemplo **ajax**

Comment: No meu sistema de avaliação por estrelas eu uso ajax, como o @ValdeirPsr sugeriu

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestão do Ajax, mas consegui fazer apenas com o PHP e JS.